# Packing complex number (Interleave vs Split ) method

Tags: opencl

For gpgpu cards such as nvidia graphic card which is the best way of packing the complex data, whether it is (split or interleave method) and why????

Comment: So that access to it can be coalesced

Answer (score 2):

Assuming hardware has **3 memory channels** and complex numbers are fp32 type,

interleaved mode:

```
complex number: C0         C1         C2         C3          C4 
bytes:          8          8          8          8           8   
memory channel: 01201201   20120120   12012012   01201201    20120120
channel-0 usage: 13 times
channel-1 usage: 13 times
channel-2 usage: 13 times
```

split mode:

```
real part:     r0         r1          r2         r3          r4
bytes:         4          4           4          4           4
memory channel:0120       1201        2012       0120        1201
imaginary has same pattern
channel-0 usage: 2x7 = 14 times
channel-1 usage: 2x7 = 14 times
channel-2 usage: 2x6 = 12 times
```

so, when reading 5 complex numbers in split mode using 3 memory channels, makes one of the channel accesses suboptimal.

Now lets assume we are reading only even (or only odd) indexed complex numbers as in doing some fft operations,

interleaved mode:

```
complex number: C0         x   C2         x          C4 
bytes:          8          x   8          x           8   
memory channel: 01201201   x   12012012   x    20120120
channel-0 usage: 8 times
channel-1 usage: 8 times
channel-2 usage: 8 times
```

split mode:

```
real part:     r0         x          r2       x          r4
bytes:         4          x           4       x           4
memory channel:0120       x        2012       x        1201
imaginary has same pattern
channel-0 usage: 2x4 = 8 times
channel-1 usage: 2x4 = 8 times
channel-2 usage: 2x4 = 8 times
```

so a 3-channel hardware doesn't get affected much.

Now let's see **8-channel memory** access:

interleaved mode:

```
complex number: C0         C1         C2         C3          C4 
bytes:          8          8          8          8           8   
memory channel: 01234567   01234567   01234567   01234567    01234567
channel-0 usage: 1 times
channel-1 usage: 1 times
channel-2 usage: 1 times
channel-3 usage: 1 times
channel-4 usage: 1 times
channel-5 usage: 1 times
channel-6 usage: 1 times
channel-7 usage: 1 times
%100 bandwidth
```

split mode:

```
real part:     r0         r1          r2         r3          r4
bytes:         4          4           4          4           4
memory channel:0123       4567        0123       4567        0123
imaginary has same pattern
channel-0 usage: 2x3 = 6 times
channel-1 usage: 2x3 = 6 times
channel-2 usage: 2x3 = 6 times
channel-3 usage: 2x3 = 6 times
channel-4 usage: 2x2 = 4 times
channel-5 usage: 2x2 = 4 times
channel-6 usage: 2x2 = 4 times
channel-7 usage: 2x2 = 4 times
half channels are used %50 more times than other half! %75 bandwidth
```

so they look equal until we get back to fft example that has odd access or even access only:

interleaved mode:

```
complex number: C0         C1         C2         C3          C4 
bytes:          8          x          8          x           8   
memory channel: 01234567   x          01234567   x           01234567
channel-0 usage: 3 times
channel-1 usage: 3 times
channel-2 usage: 3 times
channel-3 usage: 3 times
channel-4 usage: 3 times
channel-5 usage: 3 times
channel-6 usage: 3 times
channel-7 usage: 3 times
%100 bandwidth
```

interleaved mode is still efficient.

split mode:

```
real part:     r0         r1          r2         r3          r4
bytes:         4          x           4          x           4
memory channel:0123       x           0123       x           0123
imaginary has same pattern
channel-0 usage: 2x5 = 10 times
channel-1 usage: 2x5 = 10 times
channel-2 usage: 2x5 = 10 times
channel-3 usage: 2x5 = 10 times
channel 4-7 not used! %50 bandiwdth
```

so on some occasions split mode can be as slow as %50 when accessing only some of items non-contiguously using split mode.

You should benchmark for even-odd access versus full access to know which type to use.